# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am starting with angular and following a simple tutorial on YouTube. When I try to show the code in a browser I am getting the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

This is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> {{email}}</p>
    <p><strong>Address:</strong> {{adress.street}}, {{adress.city}}, {{adress.state}}</p>
    <button (click)= "toggleHobies()"> Show Hobbies</button> 
    <div *ngIf= "showHobies">  
      <h3>Hobies:</h3>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor= "let hobby of hobbies">
          {{hobby}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class UserComponent {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    address: address;
    hobbies: string[];
    showHobies: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'John Doe';
        this.email = 'John@gmail.com'
        this.address = {
            street: '12 Main st',
            city: 'Boston',
            state: 'MA',
        }
        this.hobbies = ['Music', 'Movies', 'Sports'];
        this.showHobies = false;

    }

    toggleHobies() {
        if (this.showHobies == true) {
            this.showHobies = false;
        }
        else {
            this.showHobies = true;
        }
    }

}
interface address {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
}
```

I have tried to search for an answer but could not find anything that would help me. Can you please tell me why this is occurring.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have mistyped the property name on the markup

```
adress -> address
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It should be address, not adress.

```
<p><strong>Address:</strong> {{address.street}}, {{address.city}}, {{address.state}}</p>
```